# How to change all but one value in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array called `array`

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Now if I want to change a value in `array` I could do something like

```
array[0] = 'zero';
```

But how do I change 'every' value in `array` EXCEPT for a particular one?

Basically I am looking for a shorthand for this

```
array[0] = 9;
array[1] = 9;
array[2] = 9;
//array[3] left untouched
array[4] = 9;
```

Something like

```
array[all except 4] = 9;
```

How can this be easily done with javascript?

Comment: A simple `for` loop would do the job...

Comment: You could've just searched it easily. A simple for loop, map, forEach, reduce and many more things would be the solution. Kindly research more next time and tell the community 'what all you tried' and why you couldn't achieve the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map`, testing whether the index is 4, and returning either the value at that index, or your chosen new value:

```js
const array = [
0,
1,
2,
3,
4
];
const array2 = array.map((val, i) => i === 3 ? val : 9);
console.log(array2);
```

If you need to *mutate* the original array (which usually isn't a great idea), `.map` won't work because it creates a *new* array, but you can `forEach` and reassign:

```js
const array = [
0,
1,
2,
3,
4
];
array.forEach((val, i) => {
  if (i !== 3) array[i] = 9;
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: give me 5, i'll check

Comment: I tried to accept this as the answer but it said I need to wait 8 minutes, please have patience

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the existing array using `.forEach()` with an `if` condition inside:

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    indexToSkip = 3;

array.forEach((_, i) => {
  if(i !== indexToSkip)
    array[i] = 9;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` to transform the array:

```js
var array = [0,1,2,3,4];

array = array.map((el, i) => {
  if(i != 3) el = 9;
  return el;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do a for loop as follows:

```js
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
 if(i!='insert number in array you dont want to chage'){
  some code..
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple for loop,

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(array)
var ignore = 3;
var replace = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i !== ignore) {
    array[i] = replace;
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and save the value ath the given index and restore this value.

This approach mutates the given array, as wanted.

```js
const fill = (array, all, save) => (value => (array.fill(all)[save] = value, array))(array[save]);

var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(array);
fill(array, 9, 3);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```